# jQuery UI tabs - remove header and content area behind tabs

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm currently just getting my head around transferring a SPRY tabbed panel into jQuery UI tabs, and was wondering if there was a quick way to remove the content area from behind the UI tabs. I basically want the white page background behind the tabs, and the content area to appear below the tabs. The jQuery UI version of the tabs [appears here](http://www.davidkneale.com/wcusa/expedition_leader_ui.html) and how I would like the tabs to appear can be [viewed on this page.](http://www.davidkneale.com/wcusa/expedition_leader.html) I used the jQuery Themeroller to create the original tabs style.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with CSS.

```
#copy-main .ui-widget-header{
    background:transparent !important;
}

#copy-main .ui-tabs{
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin-top:40px;
    position:relative;
}

#copy-main .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav{
    padding: 0 !important;
    position:absolute;
    margin:-32px -1px 0; //compensation
}
```

Comment: If this worked for you, you should accept my response so other people know (coming from the future, of course) that this is a method that's viable.